# Wirecloud FIWARE Lab - is NGSI HTTP proxy alive

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I already found this question, I will quote it since problem seem to be happening again "I'm creating a Wirecloud Mashup using ngsi-source operator. Until some days ago everything worked very well but now the NGSI Proxy http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org seems not to be alive".
Are there issues with this service? Unfortunately I cannot use the instance at https://mashup.lab.fiware.org:8443 as I need ngsi proxy over http.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The instance at `http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` is currently up and running (August the 16th). I don't know the status of the service on August the 10th.

> **NOTE**:
>
> Take into account that, `https://mashup.lab.fiware.org:8443` is not longer available.